# Как задать часовой пояс в javascript? (set timezone offset javascript Date)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, дата, время, timezone

Браузер жестко задает часовой пояс обьектам даты исходя из настроек часового пояса операционной системы. Но в некоторых приложениях необходимо чтобы все пользователи сайта видели буквально одно и то же время, с какого бы места на земном шаре они бы не зашли. Как можно в ручную задать смещение часового пояса  в javascript? Чтобы оно автоматически применилось ко всем обьектам Date?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

В ней это делается легко и просто:

```
var message = "Московское время: " + moment().utcOffset(3).format("HH:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Я написал крутой полифилл специально для себя и вас!
Добавляет столь желанную функцию Date.setTimezoneOffset()
Удивительно что подобное изначально не встроенно в браузер и яваскрипт.
Вот он, можете лайкнуть :3 https://github.com/uMaxmaxmaximus/date-timezone

Пример использования:

```
// Установить смещение таймзоны для всех дат
Date.timezoneOffset(-240) // +4 UTC

// Установить смещение таймзоны только для данной даты
(new Date).timezoneOffset(-180) // +3 UTC
```

Coffeescript версия:

```
do ->   
    # tmp date
    offsetDate = new Date()

    # default timezone
    Date.prototype.timezoneOffset = offsetDate.getTimezoneOffset()


    Date.setTimezoneOffset = (timezoneOffset)->
        return @prototype.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset


    Date.getTimezoneOffset = (timezoneOffset)->
        return @prototype.timezoneOffset


    Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = ->
        return @timezoneOffset


    Date.prototype.setTimezoneOffset = (timezoneOffset)->
        return @timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset


    Date.prototype.toString = ->
        offsetTime = @timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000
        offsetDate.setTime(@getTime() - offsetTime)
        return offsetDate.toUTCString()


    [
        'Milliseconds', 'Seconds', 'Minutes', 'Hours',
        'Date', 'Month', 'FullYear', 'Year', 'Day'
    ]
    .forEach (key)=>
        Date.prototype["get#{key}"] = ->
            offsetTime = @timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000
            offsetDate.setTime(@getTime() - offsetTime)
            return offsetDate["getUTC#{key}"]()

        Date.prototype["set#{key}"] = (value)->
            offsetTime = @timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000
            offsetDate.setTime(@getTime() - offsetTime)
            offsetDate["setUTC#{key}"](value)
            time = offsetDate.getTime() + offsetTime
            @setTime(time)
            return time
```

Скомпилированная версия:

```
(function() {
  var offsetDate;
  offsetDate = new Date();
  Date.prototype.timezoneOffset = offsetDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  Date.setTimezoneOffset = function(timezoneOffset) {
    return this.prototype.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset;
  };
  Date.getTimezoneOffset = function(timezoneOffset) {
    return this.prototype.timezoneOffset;
  };
  Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = function() {
    return this.timezoneOffset;
  };
  Date.prototype.setTimezoneOffset = function(timezoneOffset) {
    return this.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset;
  };
  Date.prototype.toString = function() {
    var offsetTime;
    offsetTime = this.timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000;
    offsetDate.setTime(this.getTime() - offsetTime);
    return offsetDate.toUTCString();
  };
  return ['Milliseconds', 'Seconds', 'Minutes', 'Hours', 'Date', 'Month', 'FullYear', 'Year', 'Day'].forEach((function(_this) {
    return function(key) {
      Date.prototype["get" + key] = function() {
        var offsetTime;
        offsetTime = this.timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000;
        offsetDate.setTime(this.getTime() - offsetTime);
        return offsetDate["getUTC" + key]();
      };
      return Date.prototype["set" + key] = function(value) {
        var offsetTime, time;
        offsetTime = this.timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000;
        offsetDate.setTime(this.getTime() - offsetTime);
        offsetDate["setUTC" + key](value);
        time = offsetDate.getTime() + offsetTime;
        this.setTime(time);
        return time;
      };
    };
  })(this));
})();
```

Comment: monkey patching стандартных объектов - зло. Две библиотеки, активно занимающиеся манки-патчингом, обречены на конфликт.

Comment: Что будет если две разные библиотеки добавят разные реализации setTimezoneOffset в класс Date?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тогда оно перестанет работать, программист это увидит и отключит библиотеку которая вызвала конфликт это РАЗ. На практике такого не бывает, ЭТО ДВА. САМА СУТЬ данной библиотеки ИЗМЕНИТЬ поведение стандартного объекта - то есть САМА СУТЬ И ЕСТЬ МАНКИ ПАТЧИНГ ЭТО ТРИ. Данный метод я ввел для красоты, ибо я не хочу стараться ради левых людей в интернете слишком сильно, я вам подсказал решение, дальше допиливайте кому надо. У меня данный метод конфликтов не вызывает.